# Can't reach kafka producer with node-red

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, node-red

I have installed node-red on raspberry pi 3 to collect data from sensors and then store them in kafka but now I have some issue with kafka producer node. 
I've setup a kafka server on my laptop that correctly works in console: if I send messages on kafka producer console I correctly receive it on consumer console.
Unfortunately when I try to inject a timestamp in kafka producer in node-red on raspberry, server gives no response.

- Debug page of node-red says: "BrokerNotAvailableError: Broker not available"
- In producer node ZKQuorum field I've typed the ip of the laptop and set port to 9092, as I seen in example on npm site.
- I'm sure the topic is correct.
- I'm sure zookeeper is running and kafka server also. Indeed if at same time I try to use kafka with laptop console it works great.
- I've also tried to reach kafka producer port with telnet: connections are accepted.

I've already posted same question on node-red community, without success for now.
Any hint about this issue?

UPDATE:

Update. I've tried to implement a python function in node-red to send a simple message to the kafka producer and I have obtained a deeper error log in:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 808
I opened file and at line 808 there is a function with this comment:
[image]

It can be helpful?

Comment: Which machine did you try telnet from? is there a firewall?

Comment: I used telnet from raspberry pi to my macbook, where is set up the kafka server. OS X firewall is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the accepted listeners field on the kafka server properties to the IP address of your laptop. Try to change zookeeper connect to actual ip, not localhost.

Try this property in etc/kafka/server.properties: `listeners=PLAINTEXT://<your ip here>:<kafka port here>`. you will have to restart kafka for this to take affect

Comment: Sure.

num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

############################# Zookeeper #############################

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


Now I've just tried using port 2181 but fail because there is no response from server (a centered error red boxed popup appears).
The string below the graphical node says it's connected.

Sorry I don't know how to format in comments section here.

Comment: no problem. try to change zookeeper connect to actual ip, not localhost.

Comment: Done. Nothing changed. Broker not available.

If has importance, I've installed kafka and zookeeper directly with brew.
Kafka Server starts with:    kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
Kafka consumer starts with:     kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test2 --from-beginning
Kafka producer starts with:   kafka-console-producer --broker-list localho:9092 --topic test2

Comment: Try this property in etc/kafka/server.properties: `listeners=PLAINTEXT://<your ip here>:<kafka port here>`. you will have to restart kafka for this to take affect

Comment: I have put your row in server.properties inserting kafka producer port 9092 in <kafka port here>.
Then in node-red I have put myIP:2181 where 2181 is the port of my kafka consumer.

Now I can see messages from node-red on consumer console.
I've also tried to see consumer node output in node-red and correctly works.

Just a thing. Now kafka producer console doesn't works, message sent from it don't reach consumer console, showing a timeout error. Is it normal?

Comment: what is the command you are using to start the console producer?

Comment: My fault. I wrote "localhos" instead of "localhost".
Thank you daniel, your help was very important.